# unable to access the linq to sql result in mvc4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am getting result from theee tables usign linq to sql but i am unable to use the values in the view, how i can do that as i am new to mvc

here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Grid()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your Grid page.";

    bc_limsEntities objbc_limsDBContext = new bc_limsEntities();


    var result = from b in objbc_limsDBContext.dc_tpatient_bookingm
                  join d in objbc_limsDBContext.dc_tpatient_bookingd on b.bookingid equals d.bookingid
                  join t in objbc_limsDBContext.dc_tp_test on d.testid equals t.TestId

                  where b.bookingid == 41239 && d.ProcessID == 0006 && t.SubdepartmentId == 16

                  select new {b.bookingid,
                              d.bookingdid,
                              d.testid,
                              t.Test_Name,
                              t.procedureid,
                              t.ClinicalUse,
                              t.AutomatedText};

    ViewBag.Result = result.ToList();


    return View(result);
}
```

and I am doing like this in view:

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.Result)
{
    <h1>@item</h1>
}
```

Comment: Your db context is not getting disposed. Wrap it in a `using` clause.

Comment: @asawyer is saying right i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my self by this way:

```
public class ResultSet
{
    public long bookingid { get; set; }
    public long bookingdid { get; set; }
    public long testid { get; set; }
    public string Test_Name { get; set; }
    public long procedureid { get; set; }
    public string ClinicalUse { get; set; }
    public string AutomatedText { get; set; }

}
```

and in Controller:

```
bc_limsEntities objbc_limsDBContext = new bc_limsEntities();


        var result = from b in objbc_limsDBContext.dc_tpatient_bookingm
                      join d in objbc_limsDBContext.dc_tpatient_bookingd on b.bookingid equals d.bookingid
                      join t in objbc_limsDBContext.dc_tp_test on d.testid equals t.TestId

                      where b.bookingid == 41239 && d.ProcessID == 0006 && t.SubdepartmentId == 16

                      select new {b.bookingid,
                                  d.bookingdid,
                                  d.testid,
                                  t.Test_Name,
                                  t.procedureid,
                                  t.ClinicalUse,
                                  t.AutomatedText};

        List<ResultSet> resultList = new List<ResultSet>();

        foreach (var temp in result)
        {
            ResultSet objResultSet = new ResultSet();

            objResultSet.bookingid = temp.bookingid;
            objResultSet.bookingdid = temp.bookingdid;
            objResultSet.testid = temp.testid;
            objResultSet.Test_Name = temp.Test_Name;
            objResultSet.procedureid = long.Parse(temp.procedureid.ToString());
            objResultSet.ClinicalUse = temp.ClinicalUse;
            objResultSet.AutomatedText = temp.AutomatedText;

            resultList.Add(objResultSet);
        }

        ViewBag.Result = resultList;
return View(resultList);
```

and in View like this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
          {
              <tr>
              <td class="t_center"><input type="checkbox" id="c14" name="cc" /><label for="c14"><span></span></label></td>
              <td>@item.bookingid</td>
              <td>@item.bookingdid</td>
              <td>@item.testid</td>
              <td>@item.Test_Name</td>
              <td>@item.procedureid</td>
              <td>@item.ClinicalUse</td>
              <td>@item.AutomatedText</td>

              </tr>                  
          }
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the View bag, use a View Model. You are already passing `results` as the View Model in this case, so you need to declare the model at the top of your view page, like so:

```
@model List<Item>
```

(or whatever type of object `results` is)

Then you can use it like this:

```
@foreach(var item in Mode)
{
    <h1>@item.Property</h1>
}
```

Normally, you would have a dedicated View Model class that contains a number of properties, one of which would be your `results` list, try that instead if you are feeling adventurous!

**EDIT**: Because you are dynamically creating a custom object you wont know the type, what you should do is create a class (e.g. `Item`) that has all the fields you need, and then populate that class from your three tables, then use that.

Comment: I agree. You should be creating view-model types that can be decorated with annotations and bind your views to those.

Comment: by this way my view will be populated but if on click of a particaular item, how i will get the booking id? @asawyer

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: If you want to put the booking id somewhere then use `@item.bookingid`, but this is really a different question

Answer (score -1):

How about trying something like:

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.Result)
{
    <h1>@item.bookingid</h1>
}
```

if of course you wanna stick with using the viewbag but otherwise musefan's suggestion of using a view model is much cleaner and what you should really be doing.